# I can`t visualize a output from a PointCloud2 topic on RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried with a lot of codes, but, when I try to see the output topic from PointCloud2 on rviz it doesn't show any point cloud at all, I think there is a problem with the configuration of my RVIZ, but, I don`t know what it is, I tried to reinstall it and do the same steps again, but, it didn't work, could you guys help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234116/i-can%60t-visualize-a-output-from-a-pointcloud2-topic-on-rviz/) by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on 2016-05-12**:
It started to work, but, I don't know why, it started to show the outputs, if you ever get into this situation, try to do step by step, even the configuration of rviz, there must be something missing, so check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try rostopic list on a new terminal to check if the topic is actually being published?

---

Originally posted by [torkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/26543/torkx/) with karma: 36 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on 2016-05-12**:
It was publishing, I don't know what happened, but, rviz started to show the output, thanks for remembering that, I'll keep checking future codes if it is publishing.